# How to concat data of two rows using common column in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

How to concat data of two rows using common column in hive, I tried in a below format but i am missing the order.

Input data

```
column1         column2
1000000002      AA-Test1:1
1000000002      BB-Test2:1
```

Desired Result

```
1000000002      AA-Test1:1##BB-Test2:1
```

but i am getting as

```
1000000002      BB-Test1:1##AA-Test2:1
```

I don't want to flip the values while appending.

I tried with the below query

```
CREATE TABLE Tabel1
AS
SELECT column1, concat_ws("##", COLLECT_SET(column2))
AS column2
FROM Table2 group by column1 order by column2;
```

Can someone help me.

Comment: Here is the answer, i achieved myself, just added sort_array to it.

CREATE TABLE Tabel1
AS
SELECT column1, concat_ws("##", sort_array(COLLECT_SET(column2)))
AS column2
FROM Table2 group by column1 order by column2;

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to sort by column2 and then use `concat_ws` and `collect_list`

```
create table tabel1
as
select 
    a.column1, 
    concat_ws("##", collect_list(a.column2)) as column2
from ( select column1,column2 from Table2 sort by column2 ) a
group by a.column1;
```

Comment: your answer didn't work for me, see my comments under my post for right answer.